# UINavigationController's children views don't have UINavigationItem to set the title

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have a `UINavigationController` implemented to have the kind of pop/push functionality. However, on the children views I cannot set the title of the Navigation Bar, but rather only on the first view:

[image]

On the "Buzzy" page as seen above, when I select the navigation bar, the utilities tab shows me that it is a `UINavigationItem` and I can edit its title. However, on one of the children views, such as the one with "Tappable Area", the navigation bar cannot be selected and the title cannot be added.

How do I add the title for children views as well?

Comment: put this inside viewDidLoad: `self.title = "Your Title"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag a Navigation Item object from the Objects palette (cmd-shift-L) onto the view controller and select it.

[image]

You should now be able to set the title, add UIBarButtonItems etc.

Answer (score 0):

try with self.navigationItem.title = "Your title"

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is done in view did load on the view controller:

`override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "some title"
}`

However, this only works if you have your view controller embedded in a UINavigationController. I highly recommend doing this instead of creating a navigation bar yourself. If you insist on creating a navigation bar yourself, you can change the title by doing:

`navigationBar.topItem.title = "some title"`

Comment: I have all view controllers using the same class. Will it change the title for all?

Comment: did you try this?